# bash - Find All Files with Same Name Regardless of Extension

Tags: bash, find

I am merging two movie libraries and am looking to "de-duplicate" manually via bash scripting.

Here is my thought process so far:

- Find all files with same name regardless of extension
- Delete smaller file (I have storage for days! and prefer quality!)

I could build on this, so if I can somehow make the delete part separate, I can build on it. My though being I could use ffmpeg to inspect the video and pick the better one, but I'm guessing bigger size = best option and simpler to code.

[I posted of Software Rec](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48184/merge-two-movie-libraries-software-that-will-ignore-duplicates-but-take-higher) but didn't get what I wanted so I realized bash is my best bet, but my "find" knowledge is limited and most of the answers I am finding are way to complicated, I figure this should be a simple thing.

Eg: [Find files with same name but different content?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33635/find-files-with-same-name-but-different-content)

Comment: I think I am making it over complicated, I'd prefer "Regardless of Extension" and I bet somebody will answer that way, but it would likely be much easier to use a list of possible extensions which I do know, eg (MKV/MP4/M4V/AVI/MPEG)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a nice way I wrote to just find the repeating files ignoring extension:

```
find . -exec bash -c 'basename "$0" ".${0##*.}"' {} \; | sort | uniq --repeated
```

Then I wrapped it in this loop to find the smaller of the two files for each:

```
for i in $(find . -exec bash -c 'basename "$0" ".${0##*.}"' {} \; | sort | uniq --repeated); do find . -name "$i*" -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-; done
```

Finally one more loop to (interactively, with `rm -i` so there's a prompt before every one) delete all those files:

```
for j in $(for i in $(find . -exec bash -c 'basename "$0" ".${0##*.}"' {} \; | sort | uniq --repeated); do find . -name "$i*" -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-; done); do rm -i "$j"; done
```

As this involves doing two `find`s on your directory, surely there is a better way. But this should work for simple cases. It also assumes you're working from the current directory, if you want to perform the command on a different one just change the `.` argument to both `find` commands.

Comment: The find works great, started tackeling how to compare and delete smaller file, perhaps that should have been a separate thread tho

Answer (score 1):

How I ended up doing it because of my issue with needing to exclude .srt files.

Find Files with same name but different extension:

```
ls * | sed 's/.\{4\}$//' | sort | uniq -d
```

Note: This is dependant on the extension being 4 characters eg `.XYZ`, it wouldn't work for mpeg, but all my movies are mp4/mkv/m4v.

Ignore .srt Files:

```
ls * |  awk '!/.srt/'  | sed 's/.\{4\}$//' | sort | uniq -d
```

I posted a separate thread on comparing file sizes, but Harrys Answer does a great job except I realized I had .srt issues to mitigate.

[Compare two file sizes and delete smaller file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437437/compare-two-file-sizes-and-delete-smaller-file)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: I love the downvote... So i shouldn't share then?

Comment: stackexchange is just full of people on their high horses +1, also to change it to match non 4 char extentions change the number 4. for example 1,4 matches 1-4.